# C++ making an array of pointers to const objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constants

I'm trying to make a non-constant array of non-constant pointers to constant objects. The idea is that I should be able to change what the pointers in the array point to, but what they point to is a constant object.

I'm having problem defining this array (it's an array of pointers to objects of type `Person` - a custom class). I'm currently declaring the array like so:

```
Person* people[10];
```

Also that's not explicitly saying that the pointers point to const Persons. So when I do something like this:

```
people[i] = &p;
```

where `p` is a reference to an object of type `const Person`, it fails.

Comment: `const Person *people[10]`

Comment: @NeilKirk, does this not make the array itself const? Or the pointers const? It seems there would be three different ways to declare it depending on which part you want const.

Comment: @user83643: Only two different ways, since a const array is the same thing as an array of const elements.  An array of const pointers to mutable `Person` would be `Person* const people[10];`.

Comment: `const Person *` cannot change the person, but can point to other people. `Person *const` can change the person, but can't point to anyone else. I feel I could make a joke here, but one eludes me. Putting the pointer into an array doesn't change that property of the pointer. `const Person *` == `Person const *`

Comment: **[cdecl](http://cdecl.org)** might be useful. To really learn how to read a declaration, take a look at the **[Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)**.

Comment: I think you may be confusing things when you say "non-constant array". The actual C-array itself is always 'constant', you cannot resize, move or adjust it in any fashion after it has been created. You can of course potentially modify the contents of the array.

Comment: @jweyrich: I hate spiral rule

Comment: @user83643: "does this not make the array itself const?" - That's why I prefer `Person const *people[10]` syntax, to avoid such confusions

Comment: @aschepler: Does such thing as const array ever exist?

Comment: @kotlomoy: Yes and no. 3.9.3/2: "Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type." but 3.9.3/5: "Cv-qualifiers applied to an array type attach to the underlying element type, so the notation "_cv_ `T`," where `T` is an array type, refers to an array whose elements are so-qualified.  An array type whose elements are cv-qualified is also considered to have the same cv-qualifications as its elements."

Comment: ... and so `std::is_const<const int[5]>::value` is `true`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in doubt ... use typedef (because it's explicit, adds more specialized semantics and avoids the confusion completely):

```
typedef const Person* PersonCPtr;
PersonCPtr people[10];
```

Comment: I prefer not to be in doubt!

Comment: @NeilKirk, I know (so do I). I still think it's a good idea to use a typedef, because when a declaration looks ugly/long/complicated it requires effort to understand (and this will probably hold true for other developers looking at the code in the future).